# Homebrew, list all packages which are no dependency of other installed packages

Tags: homebrew

There is the awesome vanilla list:

```
$ brew list | cat
[...]
libevent
[...]
net-snmp
[...]
openssl
openssl@1.1
[...]
```

Let's say I want to check which packages can I remove because I no longer need. I would need a way to forge such list, because if I try to randomly remove a package, e.g. `openssl@1.1`:

```
$ brew remove openssl@1.1
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.0f
because it is required by net-snmp, which is currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl@1.1
$ _
```

So my desired output would be:

```
$ /PATH/TO/brew_dependency_tree_leaves_list.sh
[...]
libevent
[...]
net-snmp
[...]
$ _
```

<sub>I don't know if `net-snmp` can be depended by any. It is not in my scenario. `libevent` is also depended upon by something else, but please abstract that.</sub>

How to?

Comment: “brew list” on its own should work (without “cat”).

Comment: "brew list" shows me a matrix of names that woulda made my OP editing harder.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
brew leaves
```

[Docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#leaves):

> List installed formulae that are not dependencies of another installed formula.

You can also use `--installed-on-request` or `--installed-as-dependency` to understand the reason a package was installed.

Comment: Now my Homebrew installation is clear, minimal, without superfluous packages no longer necessary. I had been collecting stuff for years and my installation was very cluttered.